# Apply linear gradient brush on top of another linear gradient brush

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having a css like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), linear-gradient(0deg, #532EAB 0.47%, #8D44DE 47.92%, #B163FF 100%);
```

which applies two linear gradient on a background.
Now I want to make it happen on WPF with `<LinearGradientBrush>`.
What I've tried is to add all the `<GradientStop>`  inside a `<LinearGradientBrush>`. Which gave me only one layer with wrong gradient.

```
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#532EAB"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.4792" Color="#8D44DE"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#B163FF"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="1" />
            <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Is there any solution for a background in WPF similar to the above css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine two or more gradient brushes you could use a `VisualBrush` with nested grids in it where you can set the `Background` for each. You will need also to set the size of element in the `VisualBrush`. Semitransparent brush must be by the innermost grid.

Your CSS could then looks like:

```
<VisualBrush xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Grid
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,1" EndPoint="0.5,0" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#532EAB"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0047" Color="#532EAB"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.4792" Color="#8D44DE"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#B163FF"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,1" EndPoint="0.5,0" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true">
                        <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>                
</VisualBrush>
```